# Reorder pandas DataFrame columns with mixed tuple and string columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with mixed column name types: some column names are strings and some are tuples.
Is there a way to reorder the columns without changing the types of the column names?

For example, if all columns are strings, this works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Alice", 34], 
                   ["Bob", 55]])
df.columns = ["name", "age"]
df[["age", "name"]]

# Out:
   age   name
0   34  Alice
1   55    Bob
```

If all columns are tuples, this also works with no problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 30], 
                   [6, 31]])
df.columns = [(0,0), (1,1)]
df[[(1,1), (0,0)]]

# Out[15]:
  (1, 1)   (0, 0)
0      30       5
1      31       6
```

However, if the columns are mixed strings and tuples, there is an error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Alice", 0, 34], 
                   ["Bob", 1, 55]])
df.columns = ["name", (0,0), "age"]
df[["age", "name", (0,0)]]

# Out:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

I can probably fix this by converting the tuples in the columns to strings, or the strings to tuples, then converting back.
However, what I really want to know what causes this error and if there is a way to get around it in a more elegant manner.

Comment: The error stems from the constructor `np.array` which is used when setting columns of a dataframe. You are passing mismatched data types (strings and tuples) to `np.array`, which is not consistent when it comes to arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df[np.array(["age", "name", (0,0)],dtype=object)]` works.

As you pointed out, Python is complaining since the array containing column names has both tuple and string values. But explicitly creating an array with the `dtype=object` specification tells the array to hold arbitrary objects and not complain. If the dtype argument is skipped, then the dtype is inferred, and Python assumes that the dtype is the same for the whole array, causing an error.

Comment: Do you know why this isn't an issue for mixed string and number column names, but is for mixed string and tuple column names?

Comment: Not sure, unfortunately. I ran a quick test on Python where I renamed the column with name ``(0,0)`` to the scalar ``0.`` Then ``df.columns`` gives ``#Out Index(['name', 0, 'age'], dtype='object'),`` meaning that in the case of mixed string and number column names, the object dtype is correctly inferred. But I'm not sure why this correct inference happens.